# How do I set text of a label on the root view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Before or after calling this code below from a view on the stack I would like to set the text of a label on the root view which the program will pop to.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I can do it the other way around (as below) when pushing a view controller onto the stack, but I don't know how to do it when popping off the stack

```
- (PushedViewController *) pushedViewController {
NSLog(@"Initialise view");
if (pushedViewController == nil) {
    pushedViewController = [[PushedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PushedView" bundle:nil];
}
return pushedViewController;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[TableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


Table* tableRow =[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.pushedViewController animated:YES];
self.pushedViewController.code.text = tablerow.code;

}
```

It would be appreciated if someone could tell me how to access and set variables of a view on the stack with out creating a new instance of the view.

Comment: `[[[navigationController rootViewController] textLabel] setText:@"Foo"];`

Comment: @H2CO3 When I do that I get the error "no known class method for selector rootViewController" also will that allow me to set text of a textfield?

Comment: sorry, I meant topViewController as method name.

Comment: Why are you holding onto `pushedViewController` like that? You normally create it and push it onto the navigation controller stack and then the navigationController own's it

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to have, is to make a delegate-like callback. So that your child controller would have

```
@protocol PushedViewControllerDelegate
@required

- (void)controller:(PushedViewController *)controller didUpdateSome:(id)data;

@end
```

and a property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<PushedViewControllerDelegate> delegate
```

now, you can assign your root controller to `delegate` of child controller, and it can inform back on any required changes.